# How can I check the validity of a code file?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation

I'm trying to check the validity of a particular 'stand-alone' code file from within my C#.Net app. Is there any way that I can check the file and get a visual studio's style errors list out?

I'm only interested in running a basic check to ensure that the basics would validate. I.e. all variables are declared and method names are valid.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: GenericTypeTea- can you please clarify what you mean by "Visual Studios style errors"?

Comment: @RichardOD - As in, the error reports that visual studios displays.

Comment: This seems to be a double, it is covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514169/how-to-programmatically-parse-and-modify-c-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not the same as the [referred to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514169/how-to-programmatically-parse-and-modify-c-code) (see my comment), you mention "VS style errors", consider using the `CSharpCodeProvider`. An example of its usage is in [its documentation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Call the [C# command line compiler (csc.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563(VS.80).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use static code analysis. There are a few libraries that enable this.  The one that cones to mind immediately is StyleCop. It is written in .NET so you should be able to reference and use it through code if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I didnt interpret the question as meaning this, but I can see now how it could!

Comment: Doesn't style cop just enforce coding rules?