# Programatically renaming or excluding C# classes and methods

Tags: c#, code-generation

I'm writing an HTML parser using [SharpKit](http://sharpkit.net), which outputs to Javascript; but would also like to run the same code on occasion in [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery), which outputs a binary.

The code that I have for SharpKit *almost* can be directly used in CsQuery, but not quite, as:

- The namespaces have to be changed, and function/class names changed accordingly.
- I also have a couple of classes that emulate .NET classes in Sharpkit that I don't need in the CsQuery code at all.

I'd like to be able to do is keep my code synchronized by performing these changes programatically. Is this possible? The solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514169/how-to-programmatically-parse-and-modify-c-sharp-code) are too old to work with C# 4.0, but I feel like Rosalyn should be able to do this.

Comment: You could create a wrapper class

Comment: @Steve I guess, but I was hoping for cleaner output code than that. That also doesn't solve the (admittedly less pressing) deletion question.

Comment: You don't need to delete, you just don't implement those methods in your wrapper. This is way easier, and way more cleaner than what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename methods in SharpKit using the JsMethodAttribute:

```
[JsMethod(Name="doSomething")]
public void DoSomething(){}
```

You can exclude method the same way by setting Export=false:

```
[JsMethod(Export=false)]
public void DoSomething(){}
```

You should be able to use the exact same code if you use Clr mode (requires jsclr.js library). Or by using native Js and .NET methods, while extending any missing method in JavaScript, for example, if JavaScript doesn't have a String.StartsWith method, you can either route it to a different method, or implement it yourself using extension methods.

For more extensive help and code samples, try the SharpKit forum:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sharpkit

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question - I'm trying to change the C# SharpKit code to C# CsQuery code, which have incompatibly-named APIs for things like HtmlElement, etc.