# How to write regex pattern to get a substring of a string in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract a substring from a given string using regex.

I am parsing c# code, and I need to get the variable which is checked for null value.

**Note: I save the c# code in a text file and read the lines as string value**

My string could be in following format.

```
string code = "if (!(strOld_Value == "" && strNew_Value == "") || (strOld_Value == "" && strNew_Value.ToLower() != "") ";
```

From the above input string, I need to extarct the variable names, that are checked for null values.  i.e) my desired output should be

`strOld_Value == ""`
`strNew_Value == ""`
`strOld_Value == ""`
`strNew_Value.ToLower() != ""`

It is not necessary that my string will always in the same pattern, sometimes my string can be a simple one as follows,

```
string code = "if (Name == "")"
```

In the above case, my desired output is,
`Name == ""`

Is it possible to write a generic regex pattern for this scenario? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to use/write a lexer/parser. Regex alone probably won't cut it here.

Comment: You can use Roslyn to get the AST of your code snippet and search for comparison operators: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Syntax-Analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex pattern:

```
[_0-9a-zA-Z\s\.]+[()\s]*(==|!=)\s*\"[0-9a-zA-Z]*\"
```

Comment: It fails for e.g. `if (var1 == "")`

Comment: Include 0-9 in the variable name [_0-9a-zA-Z\s\.]+[()\s]*(==|!=)\s*\"[0-9a-zA-Z]*\"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
(\w+(\.\w+[\)\(]*)*\s*(==|\!=)\s*\"\")
```

- `[\w]+` - matches any word character one or more times
- `(\.\w+[\)\(]*)*` = (matches `.` and any word character after it, and
  there can be parentheses) zero or more times
- `\s*` - optional space
- `(==|\!=)` - `==` or `!=`
- `\s*` - optional space
- `\"\"` - matches empty value (`""`)

Answer (score 1):

As spender suggests, sounds like you need the ability to parse C# code and access the names of the variables identified by the parser

See S.O. [How to programmatically parse and modify C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514169/how-to-programmatically-parse-and-modify-c-sharp-code)